# Is it possible to use React.Component just including react and reactDom as tags in the html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cdn

I've been looking for an answer and reading documentation but I still can't make it clear for me. So I'll make it simple. I want to know if it's possible to use, for example, React.Component just with react and reactDOM included as tags in my html.

I'm suspicious that I doesn't work cause I've already try id. Here's a piece of code:

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        user: []
        }
       }



      componentDidMount() {
         var _this = this;
         axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + 
         localStorage.getItem("user"))
        .then(function(res){
          _this.setState({
           items: res.data.user
           });
         })
        .catch(function(e) {
           console.log("ERROR ", e);
        })
      }

    }
```

Edited

html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js 
        " integrity="sha384- 
        ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.12.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/home.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/4.8.0/reactstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body class="nav-md">
       </body>
       </html>
```

As I've read, it's suppose that when then html loads, so it does the react code, cause it has de React.Component, then it should call componentDidMount and do the request but I don't see that this happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks all!

Comment: How are you rendering this? Did you check the console for error messages?

Comment: provide html code

Comment: Edited, but I doesn't have anything relevant as I think.

Comment: Yes this is possible (though you might not be able to use JSX), but you don't appear to be including React or ReactDOM in your html at all. If you include them in your HTML as scripts, they are globally namespaced as React and ReactDOM reespectively.

Comment: God, I put everything except those two in this example,  shame on me, as I copied  them from an html wich has content no relevant for this point, I'll edit it again.